# Autodetect links in textarea field

Tags: html, hyperlink, textarea

How can I highlight hyperlinks in textarea.
I have created a  tag as shown below

```
     <textarea
        class="textarea"
        name="input_note"
        id=""
        cols="30"
        rows="10"
      ></textarea>
```

let's say this input field is used to take a note and saves there(more like a google keep). so when the user inputs any 'links' in the input field, the links are shown as plain text instead of hyperlink. The link is also not highlight as normally has.

---input field I have saved a note with the link- 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
but when the note is displayed

```
> https://stackoverflow.com/
```

plain text is displayed and not clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. I had to replace the textarea with div because its impossible to do what you want in textarea but I gave it styling so that it looks just like a textarea.

```js
function linkify(inputText) {
  var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;
  if (inputText.indexOf("<a ")) {
    //URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
    replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<div contentEditable="false" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;"><a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a></div>');

    //URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
    replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<div contentEditable="false" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;"><a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a></div>');

    //Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
    replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
    replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<div contentEditable="false" style="display: inline-block; padding: 5px;"><a href="mailto:$1">$1</a></div>');
  } else {
    replacedText = inputText;
  }
  alert(replacedText)
  return replacedText;
}
```

```css
.textarea {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  min-height: 50px;
  /* if you want Flexible textarea/div then give min-height instead of height */
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" name="input_note" id="textarea" cols="30" rows="10" contenteditable onblur="  var text = document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML;var text = linkify(text);document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = text;"></div>
```

Stackoverflow has blocked <a tags so you wont be able to go to a website if u try to run the snippet. Copy the code in the file and it would work.

Comment: Nice job. Well done

Comment: Thank You. It looks scary but I'll try to understand it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It’s nothing to understand. You can just put the code as it is because I did everything u would want to

Comment: @Pranay, do mind if u accept this answer as the right answer to the question? If it works for u

Comment: so basically what you have done is, using regular expressions we look for the links starting with http and www and for emails and replace them. okay got it. I'm not familiar with regx so It was hard to me to understand that.I've accepted your answer as right. Thank you.

Comment: Saying the truth, I also don't understand some of the code like how did it find the URLS. I found the code to find URLS on net and then edited it to match your requirements and also added a functionality to replace it with a link.